# Team Foundation Server 2013 trace doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, team-foundation-server

I'm trying to turn on tracing on my TFS 2013 instance. To do this I'm modifying C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config file like this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="traceWriter" value="true" />
    <add key="traceDirectoryName" value="%TEMP%\\TFLogFiles" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <assert assertuienabled="false" />
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4" />
    <switches>
      <add name="API" value="4" />
      <add name="Authentication" value="4" />
      <add name="Authorization" value="4" />
      <add name="Database" value="4" />
      <add name="General" value="4" />
      <!-- WorkItem trace switches -->
      <add name="traceLevel" value="4" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

After these manipulations log files appear but they are not verbose at all. Here is all info that appears in file(s):

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:54.485] # Team Foundation Trace for component  started at 03/12/2015 11:48:54 [note all date/time values are in UTC].

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:54.487] # Trace listener: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationTextWriterTraceListener

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:54.487] # Config settings: Assert UI Enabled=False Launch Debugger=True ASP.NET=True

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.678] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.675, 7 ms, General] Entered CatalogTransactionContext.Save().

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.684] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.684, 16 ms, General] Asking for the Catalog database lock.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.692] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.692, 24 ms, General] Got the Catalog database lock.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.692] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.692, 24 ms, General] Running the catalog rules.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.709] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.708, 40 ms, General] Finished running the catalog rules.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.709] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.709, 41 ms, General] Calling the catalog database to save the changes.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.763] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.763, 95 ms, General] Returned from the catalog database after saving changes.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.763] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.763, 95 ms, General] Finished building the returned catalog objects.

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.769] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.769, 101 ms, General] Exiting CatalogTransactionContext.SaveCatalogChanges().

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.924] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : [Info, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.922, 254 ms, API] Raising Status Changed for xxxxxxxx-zzzz-yyyy-aaaa-000000000000 with status Started

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.961] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Updated Trace Settings

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:55.961] w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Initialized the Trace Configurations

[, PID 3304, TID 3064, 2015/03/12 11:48:56.014] Registering Tagging routes

I tried to apply the same changes to the TFS 2010 instance and achieved desired results: I receive extremely verbose logs. Any ideas how to hack TFS 2013 to work?

**Update:**

Discussion on MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a57bb4e7-d30a-44dd-86d0-170485344dab/team-foundation-server-2013-trace-doesnt-work

Bug on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1185821/team-foundation-server-2013-trace-doesnt-work

Bug for TFS 2015 RC2 on Microsoft Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1622187

Don't forget to vote up this issues if you have the same problem!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as you are not really meant to mess with that stuff?

Comment: I have some corrupted Work Items that cannot be modified because of "TF237079: Team Foundation could not update the work item because it was already updated by another user, it does not exist, or you do not have permission to update it" error. I read a lot of post about this error but none of them help. So, I want to have my own investigation.

Comment: Dumb question: have you applied this change to all Application Tier nodes?

Comment: We have only one app tier node

Comment: I tried to apply exact tracing configuration changes on 2 different TFS 2013 instances and one TFS 2010. I received expected results only on 2010 instance.

Comment: So, why are you not raising a support ticket with Microsoft?

Comment: Maybe I made some dummy mistake or missed some step specific for this version. Maybe the problem is specific to my deployment and server configuration. Maybe somebody already faced with this problem and have an answer and will share it with community... and lots of other "maybes"

Comment: You should raise a support call. There is no configuration or mishap that should result in errors accessing some work items.

Comment: Hurray! MS marked this issue as fixed. Waiting for TFS 2015 release!

Comment: Maybe anybody had a chance to check if the issue was fixed in latest TFS version (2015 RC2)?

Comment: OK, I had a chance to check it with TFS 2015 RC2. It is still an issue... It can only log General info. Added one more ticket for MS.